# CPAN 1.61 has issue with embedded space in path within Cygwin on Win7

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I’m a mere mortal using Cygwin on Win7 and wanting to develop perl scripts using SOAP::lite.  Installation instructions I found at soaplite.com directed me to start with `perl –MCPAN –e shell` before attempting an `> install SOAP::lite`

The newb in me didn’t appreciate that my windows user profile has a space character in it and the CPAN set-up seemed to go all horribly wrong around the point where the script was writing make files for local::lib, MYMETA.yml and MYYMETA.json.  I got “no such file or directory” messages quoting only the portion of the path that followed the space in my user profile.

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 UKLHRL00020 2.0.4(0.287/5/3) 2015-06-09 12:22 x86_64 Cygwin
$ cpan --version
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
/usr/bin/cpan version 1.61 calling Getopt::Std::getopts (version 1.06 [paranoid]),
running under Perl version 5.14.4.
[Now continuing due to backward compatibility and excessive paranoia.
See ``perldoc Getopt::Std'' about $Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION.]
Nothing to install!
```

When I ran `perl –MCPAN –e shell` for the first time, it did report “Warning: You do not have write permission for Perl library directories.” and I elected for the default option [local::lib] for the approach to be taken.

So what can I do next?

Looking closer at the Cygwin’s setup-x86_64.exe, a search for “cpan” lists eight packages under the perl category for perl-CPAN-* and perl-Parse-CPAN*, which are all set to “Skip”.  The package perl-CPANMeta: Perl distribution CPAN-Meta is version 2.150001-1 from cygwin.mirrors.pair.com.  Since this is not installed yet, but the installed Perl5 has some knowledge of an old CPAN, I need to know if it is safe to install the latest and will it work with a space in my profile?   Do I need to remove the old CPAN, and how?

Comment: Why is your Windows profile used at all? Is that where you installed cygwin?

Comment: Tis a laptop after all :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to update to the latest version of [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker), recent versions contain various fixes for paths containing spaces. This should fix these issues.

Comment: According to Cygwin's setup-x86_64.exe the ExtUtils::MakeMaker is not installed (Skip), neither are any of the perl-CPAN packages.  Clearly the CPAN and MakeMaker modules that were executed are those embedded with the perl-base (v5.14.4-3) package.  Are you suggesting I install the ExtUtils::MakeMaker and the Perl::CPAN packages and then try again and if so Will these new modules take precedence over any existing modules?

Comment: Indeed, that is exactly what I'm proposing

Comment: I installed that and then every other module that I could see mentioned as missing or as dependency, from XML::Parser::Lite  to MIME::Parser, to Test::XML, to Test, to XML::Parser, to Test::MockObject, to XMLRPC::Test, to SOAP::Transport::TCP… everything I try leads to more implied errors. I'm unsure how to interpret the unnecessarily long reports that get spewed from the CPAN install scripts. But now SOAP::Lite won’t install because XML::Parser::Lite is missing, and XML::Parser::Lite won’t install because of some obscure reason that’s unclear to mere mortals. I need to start a new thread.

Comment: I pretty much gave up with Perl and SOAP::Lite within Cygwin, though I now see there's a new version of SOAP::Lite available.  I made better headway with Strawberry Perl for Windows, even though the `make test` also had some minor errors it did still install.  My scripts work :)